# How to make delivery time slot more clear to customers?

Tags: usability

I have a mobile app for groceries shopping, the customer chooses the items, specify the delivery address and the delivery time slot.

The times slots are presented as following:
Sat 18/2/217 
11:00 am -1:00 pm
01:00 pm -03:00 pm
03:00 pm -05:00 pm

and so on for the other week days.

The problem is the customers understands the time slot that the order will be delivered on 11:00 am because he has chosen 11:00 am-1:00 pm and if the order is being delivered on 1:00 pm he sends a message "the order was delivered too late".

How can I make the time slots more clear to customers and make them understand that the time slot means the order will be delivered in the time between ?

Comment: Have you looked at other sites to see how they achieve the same thing? This is actually a common task with a lot of delivery companies. You could even check supermarket websites, because they also offer delivery slots. No sense reinventing the wheel :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like range selector:
[image]

**Pro:**

- The time slot looks more **prominent visually**
- Customers will select the time slot in **more conscious way**, as the control requires more cognitive efforts
- Customers can select more **flexible options**

**Con:**

- The control requires more cognitive efforts and more time to perform the operation
  .

This is a balance between business goals and usability. Try A/B testing to compare the options.

Slowing down the interaction isn't always bad:

> Facebook actually slows down its interface to make users feel safe.
>
> Wells Fargo admitted to slowing down its app's retinal scanners, because customers didn't realize they worked otherwise, while various services on the web including travel sites, mortgage engines, and security checks are all making a conscious effort to slow down their omnipotent minds because our puny human brains expect things to take longer.

[Source](https://www.fastcodesign.com/3061519/evidence/the-ux-secret-that-will-ruin-apps-for-you/)

My point is the same: make the selection is more conscious for users.